# Where/how to advertise a Stack Overflow android app I made?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, android

I had a little free time, and wrote a very basic SO app for droids using AIDE (wrote it on a droid, too). It is completly non-profit, and I intend to keep it that way (no ads, and will be distributed for free).

Who would download/use this app? And where should I put a link?

Comment: Put it on your profile, maybe?

Comment: And who would see it there?

Comment: Well SO isn't going to give you free advertisement, I'm pretty sure. It *might* be suitable on http://stackapps.com/

Comment: I'm not trying to sell anuthing, just make it simpler for mobile users to get on SO

Comment: How is your app different from the mobile site?

Comment: It launches the mobile site w/out invoking browser, andattmpts to log you on using stored browser data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would definitely be okay to post it on StackApps along with [the other Android apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=android) for Stack Exchange.

I'd also post it in your Stack Overflow profile as suggested in the comments.  You currently don't have anything there, and people *do* look at profiles when you're helpful.  My SO profile ranks on the first page of a Google search for my user name, along with my blog and information about a cartoon character with the same name (imposter!), so profiles can get some exposure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still can't upvote an answer to my own frggin' question.